# Adding an input format in Druid via extension

Tags: druid, druid-extensions

I wish to parse an overly complicated json format in Druid by adding a custom extension. I followed the instructions in the [documentation](https://druid.apache.org/docs/latest/development/modules) to create a module and implemented `InputFormat` and `InputEntityReader`.

I ran `mvn package` and copied the generated artifact to the extensions folder following instruction from an [example repo](https://github.com/implydata/druid-example-extension). I updated the `druid.extensions.loadList` in `conf/druid/auto/_common/common.runtime.properties` (I even tried updating it everywhere else).

The new format is called `otlp` which I expected to see in the console while trying to parse the data but it is not. Am I missing something?

[image: input format menu in Druid console]

Comment: Hey you may wanna pose this question in the #dev channel on Apache Druid Slack.

Comment: Not sure what is wrong with your extension, have you tried to use SQL Based ingestion with JSON_VALUE functions to parse the individual columns? https://druid.apache.org/docs/latest/querying/nested-columns#transform-data-during-sql-based-ingestion